# angular pascalprecht.translate ng stands for

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

If I peep into the source module
I can see

```
angular.module('pascalprecht.translate', ['ng']).
```

ng stands for what ?
afaik there is no module named ng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is a `ng` module - it is the default AngularJS module that holds most of the services, directives etc.:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/AngularPublic.js#L143

In this context `ng` stands for aNGular.

I'm surprised to see the explicit reference to the `ng` module as normally it is not needed - reference to the default module is added if not present.